# Why the speed of MemoryMappedFile.CreateViewAccessor depends on mapped size

Tags: .net, memory-management

I have a performance problem when sharing large files between processes. All processes are x64 and I don't get any exceptions. However once files getting bigger I noticed that the speed of MemoryMappedFile.CreateViewAccessor is linearly depended on the size of the requested view. E.g. for a 5GB file is 0.1 sec on my system.

When using native PInvoked MapViewOfFile I did not notice such behaviour although I cannot be 100% sure since MapViewOfFile executes very fast (in 0.0002 sec for 5GB). I use .Net 4.5.1.

Can someone please shed some light on the issue: why CreateViewAccessor depends on the size of the view and why it is so much slower then native call?

Comment: Don't really know anything about this, but here's a guess: A basic principle in .Net is that all objects that are allocated to your program are zeroed out, as opposed to prior environments where it was more typical that memory allocated to your program may contain previous garbage. So maybe it is zeroing out the 5 GB of storage for you?

Comment: I am afraid this must be something else. I actually open an existing file for reading purposes which already contains data.